# Python destructor not called

Tags: python

Anyone has any idea how to get my destructor called on object destruction?

```
def __del__(self):
    os.unlink(self.pidfile)
```

Scenario: There is a Daemon that runs Process. Daemon gets a SIGTERM, and immediately sends a SIGTERM to Process. Process stops execution without `__del__` called.

Comment: Are there still references to that stopped process?

Comment: You can't.  Finalizers are not guaranteed to run.  Use [the `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) instead of `__del__()`.  Then set a signal handler for `SIGTERM` that raises an exception which the `with` statement can react to.

Comment: @Kevin: Finalizers aren't guaranteed to run, but we actually have more problems than that, because context manager `__exit__`s and `finally` blocks don't run by default either when Python gets a SIGTERM.

Answer (score 5):

As referenced in the comments, defining an `__exit__` method for your object and using [the with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is the preferred way of "destructing" objects.  It's more explicit and predictable.

However, even using the `with` statement won't guarantee clean destruction of your object if a SIGTERM is received.  In order to do something when a signal is received, you'll have to add a signal handler.

```
import signal
import sys

def handle_signal(signum, frame):
    print('Got signal')
    #  Do some cleanup
    sys.exit(signum)  # Maybe ???

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handle_signal)
```

At this point, you might consider calling `del your_object` in the signal handler, but even that is not guaranteed to call the `__del__` method if there are still references to that object in the program (see the docs for [__del__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__del__#object.__del__))

So bottom line I think is not to expect things to go absolutely smoothly and predictably if you're depending on SIGTERM to close your Python programs.

Comment: sys.exit raises SystemExit so it will run `__exit__` cleanup code automatically.